# Query builder how to use "where" clause on populated documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm having some issues using the Mongoose queries. I'm just trying to find documents in a collection using the **where** clause.

Unfortunately, **it seems you can't use the where clause on populated documents**.

---

This is the collection schema

```
const schema: Schema = new Schema({
    game: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game', required: true, index: true },
    players: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Player', required: true, index: true }],
    scores: [{ type: String }],
    resultDate: { type: Date}
});
```

I'm trying to find all games where *type* = **1v1**, so I tried this

```
let query = Matchs.find()
    .populate('game')
    .populate('players')
    .where('game.name').equals('Trackmania')

const matchs: Match[] = await query.exec();
```

This returns an empty array.

---

Notes

- Removing the where clause returns the correct results (all Matchs)
- Any where clause on game returns an empty array
- **I'd like to use query builder instead of passing a json** because I use some parameters to define what I am querying

I read that where clause didn't work on nested documents, but there must be a way to do this right ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Lookup and Match instead of Where.

```
MatchesModel.aggregate([

const GameName =  req.query;

  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"games", // name of the foreign collection
    "localField":"game",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"game"
  }},
   {"$lookup":{
    "from":"players", 
    "localField":"players",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"players"
  }},
  {"$match":{
     "game.name":{
      "$eq": GameName
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't use query builder :/